# How to know the jquery name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I see a lot of JQuerys used in several websites. How to know the name of that JQuery. I don't know if there is a manual for the new JQuerys.

Example: What is the name of jQuery which build the main news Block in this [URl](http://demo.tagdiv.com/newsmag_travel/)?

Comment: Look at the resources tab in your browser's developer tools and look what JavaScript (including jQuery) plugins and libraries they link to, and use.

Comment: I know how to inspect elements and use developer tools, but I didn't see any special thing in javascript

Comment: Right click and click view source and search for jquery. In  given url version is as below http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.11.1

Comment: The news block is probably generated by Wordpress' PHP in the server.

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$.fn.jquery` to get the current jQuery version.

Type it into the console (press F12 on Chrome) and you'll see that your example uses jQuery `1.11.1`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? You may not like the question, but this is a valid answer. [You should downvote when](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) it is a sloppy answer with no explanation.

Answer (score -2):

As pointed by @suyesh

"Right click and click view source and search for jquery. In given url version is as below ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/..."

[image: devtools print]